# How can I get albine() to be recognized as a function in Rstudio?

Tags: r, function, graphics, rstudio

> albine(reg=acorn.pl.reg, col="red")
>   Error in albine(reg = acorn.pl.reg, col = "red") : 
>     could not find function "albine"

Comment: What is it you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error. I think you want to use the function `abline` and you wrote `albine`.